# Using Google Play Services Location API to get listen for location services updates

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I am trying to use Google Play Services' Location API (com.google.android.gms.location) to **listen** for updates to location services (i.e. user turns on/off location in system settings).

I know that I can **poll** for this info:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;


LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();

// ...

SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
```

I also know that I can use **android** SDKs to **listen**:

```
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings

private BroadcastReceiver locationServicesBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            boolean isEnabled = locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        }
    }
};
```

But can I use Play Services APIs **and** listen?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play services are newer and offer better capabilities about managing such type of requests; they are more affordable. They handle memory, battery usage and connection far better than the old android.location libraries. [Here it is where google deprecate it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary)